# What's the point of a main function and/or __name__ == "__main__" check in Python?

Tags: python

I occasionally notice something like the following in Python scripts:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do stuff like call main()
```

What's the point of this?

Comment: After you read about this in the Python documentation, what *specific* question can you ask?  See http://docs.python.org/library/python.html for example.  After you read this section, what *specific* questions do you have.

Comment: S.Lott: His question seems specific enough. He's asking what that condition is generally for...

Comment: I was wondering about this question myself last night.

Comment: @Fragsworth:  I can't see how this is "specific".  "What's the point of..." questions are open-ended.  They don't solve a programming problem.  Also, the answer to "what's the point" is in the documentation.  It would be nice to have a more focused question that isn't -- trivially -- part of the documentation.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found quickly using Google (probably more quickly than taking the time to type the question).  I don't see why this question got upvoted 5 times (so far).  Questions like this create a lot of noise and just duplicate existing information that is easily found.

Comment: Alright, alright, mea culpa (voted to close).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Having all substantial Python code live inside a function (i.e., **not** at module top level) is a crucial performance optimization as well as an important factor in good organization of code (the Python compiler can optimize access to local variables in a function much better than it can optimize "local" variables which are actually a module's globals, since the semantics of the latter are more demanding).

Making the call to the function conditional on the current module being run as the "main script" (rather than imported from another module) makes for potential reusability of nuggets of functionality contained in the module (since other modules may import it and just call the appropriate functions or classes), and even more importantly it supports solid unit testing (where all sort of mock-ups and fakes for external subsystems may generally need to be set up before the module's functionality is exercised and tested).

Comment: I shall never put all my code in the module top level again. Thank you.

Comment: This was a better explanation for me than the one with thousands of votes. I couldn't really see the point even after all the examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This allows a python script to be imported or run standalone is a sane way.

If you run a python file directly, the `__name__` variable will contain `__main__`. If you import the script that will not be the case. Normally, if you import the script you want to call functions or reference classes from the file.

If you did not have this check, any code that was not in a class or function would run when you import.

Answer (score 7):

The sole purpose of this, assuming it is in `main.py`, is so other files can `import main` to include classes and functions that are in your "main" program, but without running the source code.

Without this condition, code that is in the global scope will be executed when it is imported by other scripts.

Answer (score 3):

It's a great place to put module tests. This will only run when a module is run directly from the shell but it will not run if imported.